# Not able to use bluetooth in ubuntu 20.04 as well as 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

I am not able to use (toggle) **bluetooth** with **ubuntu** since long time. I have dual booted my laptop with window 10 and ubuntu **22.04.1**.
I was using 20.04 with same bluetooth issue so thought to upgrade ubuntu to 22.04.1 LTS, but after successfully upgrade bluetooth issue is still there.

When I click on bluetooth it shows:
[no bluetooth found plug in a dongle to use bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXip8.png)

**`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth :`**

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81bf]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
Kernel modules: rtl8188ee
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b56c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

**`lsusb :`**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b56c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**`sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth:`** 
no output

**`sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service :`**

```
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Nov 22 11:11:36 prashantk01-notebook systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Nov 22 11:13:04 prashantk01-notebook systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Nov 22 11:23:19 prashantk01-notebook systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

is it some hardware or driver issue? Because I am able to use bluetooth with windows on this pc